# Can pip copy dependency source into my virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, django-1.7

I am a bloody beginner in Python and Django. To set up a environment on my Windows machine, I performed the following steps.

1. Install Python 3.4
2. Use pip to install virtualenv
3. Create a project folder and set up a virtualenv there
4. Download Django 1.7b1 release from the official site
5. Extract the archive in my downloads folder
6. Install it into my virtualenv

For the last step, I used pip from my virtualenv.

```
[project]\scripts\pip.exe install -e [downloads]\Django-1.7b1
```

From the global python interpreter I can't `import django`, as expected. When using the python executable from the virtualenv, it works. But the import only succeeds as long as I have the Django source in my downloads folder. Instead, I would like to include it into my virtualenv.

Can I make pip to automatically copy the Django source into my project folder?

Comment: why don't you use the python in your virtualenv to install Django into the environment

Comment: @misspec I use pip in my virtualenv to install it and python from my virtualenv to import it. That should be correct, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, when you install a package, it's put into `<virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Also, you don't need to download a package. A lot of times you can just do `pip install <package>==<version>`

Comment: @LucianU Alright, good to know. However, this doesn't work for the beta release. In my Python 3.4 virtualenv, the folder is just `lib\site-packages`. For some reason, it wasn't put into that directory though.

Comment: @danijar I've updated my answer, have a look. You're missing the target directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `django` via pip *inside* the virtualenv. I'm running Linux but you should be able to run the commands on windows.

If you need a version that's not in [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), download the package and install it to the virtualenv `site-packages`-folder.

My `site-packages` folder for `project` is in `~/venvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.
To install there:

```
pip install downloads/Django-1.7b1.tar.gz -t ~/venvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Django will install to the `site-packages` folder and is now importable from within the virtualenv. `Downloads/Django-1.7b1` is no longer needed.

Below is an example where I'm installing Django 1.7b1 from a local archive to the `site-packages`-folder of my virtualenv:

```
(project)msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ pip install /tmp/Django-1.7b1.tar.gz -t ~/venvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
Unpacking ./Django-1.7b1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///tmp/Django-1.7b1.tar.gz
    -- SNIP --
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...
(project)msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python -c "import django;print django.get_version()"
1.7b1
(project)msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ deactivate
# I've got a really old version installed globally, but you can see
# that the installation worked.
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python -c "import django;print django.get_version()"
1.5.1
```

After this you should find the following output when doing `pip freeze` while the virtualenv
is activated:

```
(project)msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ pip freeze
Django==1.7b1
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: I can't use `pip install django` for the beta release, that's the problem. By the way, I took a look at virtualenvwrapper but it's not available for Windows. However, this shouldn't be a concern here.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in the answer? `pip install downloads/Django-1.7b1 -t ~/venvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: I uninstalled Django first and ran this command then. Now, I can't `import django` neither with nor without downloads folder still present.

Comment: And you have activated your virtualenv? What is the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: No, I hadn't activates my virtualenv because I thought that manually running `scripts\pip.exe` and `scripts\python.exe` instead using them from PATH would work. However, after activating the virtualenv, I could successfully install Django even without specifying the `-t` flag. Also `pip freeze` outputs `Django==1.7b1` now. Thanks a lot for your help.